# How to support multiple languages in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

I am working on a web forms application that needs to support multiple languages based on a user's preference.  Here are some considerations to keep in mind about the needed solution:

*I want to avoid using resource files to store the different text translations because I'd like the ability to change them without having to recompile and deploy the application.*

*Also the translations ideally need to be adminstratable.*

It seems its a considerable amount of effort to add this support to an existing application.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need languge tables for each supported language. You may need to start with an "en" table as your base language for the app.

Then you can add tables for en-gb, en-us and if required you can even go brand specific using custom cultures like en-gb-MyApp1, en-gb-myApp2

Make extensive use of caching and write a custom resource provider.

Answer (score 3):

Rick Strahl has and awesome solution that is free for personal use, src available [here](http://www.west-wind.com:8080/svn/WestwindWebToolkit/trunk/) via SVN:

[West Wind Web & Ajax Toolkit for ASP.NET](http://www.west-wind.com/WestWindWebToolkit/)

**Data Driven Localization Resource Provider**
Database driven Localization lets you store resources in a SQL Server database.

- Interactive Web based Resource
  Adminstration provides a live Web
  based adminstration for that can edit
  and update resources while the app is
  running
- Resource Editing Control associates
  icons with each localizable control
  and allows jumping directly to the
  administration form with the current
  resource id  and locale selected.
- Resx Import and Export lets you
  import existing Resx resources,
  interactively edit them with the data
  driven provider, then export them
  back out as Resx resources.
- Localization Utilities like a
  JavaScript Resource Handler,
  functions to embed localized script
  values and much more.

Answer (score 0):

I b[logged about my design](http://martinnormark.com/2008/06/10/designing-for-internationalization) of an E-commerce store where products, pages etc. are stored in database, and saved in multiple languages by storing column data in XML format.